# Search Param in block title magento2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, page-title

I need to add the search param in the title of the block.
Currently i have on catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Searched For: </argument>
            </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

The above displays

> Searched For:

However, I need to display

> Searched For: test

as the title of the catalog search

Comment: Are you want to change Search Result for : test to Searched For:test?

Comment: No, I am able to display "Searched For: ", but i need to display "Search For: {searchWord}"

Comment: You dont need to do using xml you have to just create en_US.csv file in your theme and replace "Search results for: '%1'","Searched for: '%1'"

Comment: can you please be a bit more elaborate!

Comment: Have you create custom theme?

Comment: yes i have custom theme.
i am really sorry for bugging,, but i am quite new to magento 2

Comment: please check my updated answer. let me know if you have any query

Comment: Is below code working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do using xml file.

**You can simply do it using csv file.** 
You have to just create **en_US.csv** file in your theme.

`app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv` file.

Add below line in your csv,

```
"Search results for: '%1'","Searched For: '%1'"
```

After changes above,

Run deploy command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear cache.

Comment: I tried this, but did not work.. Instead i removed page title xml and called in a custom block

Comment: Its working fine may be you have placed this csv file at wrong place.

Comment: Could be. i placed it in Magento_CatalogSearch/il8n/en_US.csv
also at {Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv

then refreshed cache etc, it just showed %1 ,

Comment: You have to remove from Magento_CatalogSearch/il8n you have to keep inside only {Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n and run deploy command.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?